# Want to use exposed filters to pass arguments to a view

Tags: views

The title explains a lot.

I have a view which shows everything of the content type and has exposed filters.(<-main view)

Now I made another view where I used the exposed form style because I want it to act as a "search block". It shares the same filters as the main view and I want this to pass its arguments to the main one.

For example: A user is on the main page, fills in the filters, submits-> Redirects to the main view where the filters the user filled in are now being used.

I looked for a lot of solutions but couldnt find any.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your view on right hand side there is "Advance" toggle under that "Expose form" is there click on Exposed form in block "No" to "Yes". Now you can find that expose filter in system block. You can place that block anywhere you want you will redirect to that main view.

Comment: There is no such option?

Comment: I am using views 7.x-3.11 and i can find this Under relationships toggle in views.

Comment: Would you be so kind to provide a screenshot? I am using the latest drupal version and checked thoroughly but it is not there :D

Comment: Ok you cand find this [link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B6B_ithiawXGM3p5dUFzYkNxcjQ/view?pli=1) over here.

Comment: @JaymevG check that your views has page display or block display. Because this option is only available in Page display.

Comment: Yes, it requires views page to be created.

Comment: Yep it worked, thank you for your time and explanation! It helped me greatly!

Answer (score 1):

1. First add views using **Page** display.
2. On right side under **Advance > Exposed Form > Exposed Form in block > Yes**
3. Now you can see an expose filter block is created automatically. Go to **admin > structure > blocks** find and place your newly created block at desired region. You can check that it will redirect to that main view.